# Safe catchError?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monad-transformers

When writing code with `MonadError`, a `catchError` can turn a failing computation into a successful one. Unfortunately, the given handler function can fail itself, so there are no guarantees as to whether the resulting computation is successful. I was considering to escape the `MonadError`:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
 safeCatchError' :: Monad m =>
                    (forall e n. (Error e, MonadError e n) => (n a, e -> m a)) ->
                    m a
 safeCatchError' (c, h) = either h return (c `asTypeOf` Left "e = String")
```

This version does not deal with transformer stacks though. So what about the following extension?

```
safeCatchError :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) =>
                  (forall e n. (Error e, MonadError e n) => (t n a, e -> t m a)) ->
                  t m a
```

Can this function be defined reasonably? If yes, how? If no, why not? What extra assumptions are necessary? It can be defined for `t = ReaderT a`.

Comment: I suspect that some `(m a -> n b) -> t m a -> t n b` like `mapReaderT` is required to achieve the goal.